# CSS images alignment

Tags: html, css

I have 3 images placed inside three li elements of a ul. I wanted these images to align at the center. So, I remove margin and padding of ul and just padding of the li elements. Then, these li elements were asigned a width of 30% each. That leaved me remaining 10% space, since the entire ul was 100%. Then margin-left and margin-right for li were set as 1.66% ( (100-90)/6 ). this didn't align these images at the center. please suggest a way so that the margins at the first child of li and that of the last's are the same.

Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%
}

li {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 1.66%;
margin-right: 1.66%;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `text-align:center`?

Comment: can u tell me about it's working?

Comment: Theoretically, you shouldn't need to use margins. Just add `text-align:center` to your `li` element and it should work. And by the way, your li elements currently have 100% width, which may also be causing some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left;` instead of `display: inline-block;` as it holds 4 pixels margin by default but if you still want to use inline-block then alternatively you can use `font-size: 0;` for your parent div that is `ul`

---

And another things as you mentioned in your question there is no 30% width in your code for `li` define it `30%;`

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't write it here. it's there in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take advantage of CSS3's nth child option and set the left and right column images margin/padding. So you can only set properties to the first element and third one.

Here you can find more clear, concise info about nth child http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ or http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an alternate method. Using tables may alleviate a large amount of the trouble caused by using in-line blocks.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

table, table img
{
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="2%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="test.jpg"></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="test.jpg"></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="test.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

By using tables, you can change the distance between each cell just by using the `cellpadding` inline attribute of the `<table>` element and you can change the alignment of the content in the cells by changing the `align` attribute of the `<td>` element.

The result:

[image: Result]

3 evenly-spaced images taking up the full size of the browser window (or whatever container they are placed in).

Example in a 500px-wide container (the black border denotes the container):

[image: Result #2]